# AWS Cloudwatch Rules and Glue with Separate Environment Dev, QA, Staging and Prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

We have an AWS hosted solution which uses Cloudwatch Rules, Lambdas, AWS Glue, Databases and Docker containers. 
We need a separate environment for dev,qa...
Databases and Docker containers can be part of different VPC in the same account for different environments. But what is the standard practice of having Cloudwatch Rules, Lambdas and AWS Glue for different environment. 
For AWS lambdas alone we see there is a Versioning concept for this. But nothing found for AWS Glue and Cloudwatch. 
What is the standard practice in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AWS Glue (Serverless) is spinning up the required number of servers/clusters in the backend with configurations(VPC, subnet & SG) that you gave while adding the connection to your glue job.
Also the simple way to differentiate when you are using the same account for different environments in different vpc, is naming convention, **follow a standard naming convention with environment be the prefix for all your rsources names.**

example:
dev-flightsdata-processing-job
qa-flightsdata-processing-job

Comment: Ok. I agree that many of them say that we need to identify based on some naming conventions.